# Regex for 24 hours

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
^(([8]))$|^((([0-7]))$|^((([0-7])).?((25)|(50)|(5)|(75)|(0)|(00))))$
```

but how can I get it to work for 24 hours instead of 8 hours?

Sorry guys i realise this might be strange looking i copied it off a website, my brain cant work out regex for some reason

What i'm trying to get is hours worked but in quarters Eg.

```
3.25 < Acceptable
3.33 < Bad
5.50 < Acceptable
23.25 < Acceptable
24.25 < Bad ( Over limit of 24 )
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: What a mess of a regex!! Try removing some parenthesis first so someone might be able to read it ;)

Comment: what is (75) here ?

Comment: Please show some examples of what should be matched and what should not be matched by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
^((0?[0-9])|1\d|2[1-3])(\.((25)|(50)|(5)|(75)|(0)|(00)))?$
```

Although you can clarify better what 75 stands here for

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qxXOER/1)

Comment: @LukeSmith and have you checked the answer ?